# Quicker Confirmation

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

How can i speed up a transaction that has already been in progress for a few hours and still has yet to be confirmed?????? Ive been trying to make this transaction for days and thought i lost my funds altogether but i figured that out but im brand new to bitcoin and the whole transaction process seems effortless but yet other than transferring to my bitcoin wallet ive had no success. I need this transaction to go thru asap. Someone please help me!!!!!